# Overriding a template argument in grandchild class in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have the following hierarchy

```cpp
template<class SettingsType>
    class TemplatedBase;

class A : public TemplatedBase<SettingsTypeA>;

class B : public A;

class SettingsTypeA;

class SettingsTypeB : public SettingsTypeA;
```

Is there a way to override the template specialization in `B` so it inherits from `A` while having the template specialization `SettingsType` set to `SettingsTypeB`

Comment: Feels like XY problem. What exactly are you trying to achieve? And how much can you modify the code? Whatever you want to do it's likely possible with some modifications to A and/or B.

Comment: @DanM., it's kinda more complex problem. I have a code base where class `A` was written then someone decided its implementation can be used for different things according to different settings, same strategy, just a different setting types. So he added a conditional check on a parameter he passed in the constructor to pick the correct settingType but the system depends on the passed template argument SettingsType to instantiate few objects on need.

Comment: Can you change the implementation of A? I'm also not sure if I understand how does "conditional check in the constructor to pick the correct settingType" mesh with the template argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple change would be to template `A` while giving it a default:

```
template<typename T = SettingsTypeA>
class A : public TemplatedBase<T> {};
```

and then you can use the needed type when `B` inherits from `A`:

```
class B : public A<SettingsTypeB> {};
```

Comment: But does `class A : public TemplatedBase<SettingsTypeB>` make sense/compile? The question is phrased as if it doesn't, but info is insufficient to decide.

Comment: @DanM. Things need to be declared in the right order, but apart from that, it seems fine.

Comment: I tried this, but I get `Class A is not a template type`

Comment: Seems [fine](https://godbolt.org/z/3sWjdK). Just had to reorder things, and add `{}`.

Comment: Well, the error did exist due to having an unnecessary forward declaration in another file for that class. I removed it and it worked as expected. I also did utilize explicit template instantiation as I know the subclasses are limited and only a known subset is used.

Answer (score 2):

No.
Template is not a class. It's a *template*.

`TemplatedBase<SettingsTypeA>` is a specific instantiation of the template - it's just the regular `Foo` class. There is nothing special about it beyond that.

So your question is the equivalent of asking if you can change `C` for `D` in below example:

```
class A : public C;

class B : public A;
```